# What is the main differences of Pricing tier in Active Directory in Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

Am creating an Active Directory in Azure. At the time of creating an AAD, am not able to decide which pricing tier I want to choose in both Premium1 and 2. Can you suggest me, which pricing tier is suitable for max 15 users can perform actions at a time.

Comment: Have you seen this: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/pricing/details/active-directory/?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pricing tiers like Basic and Premium are licenses which are assigned to users.

Mostly they offer better capabilities like self-service password reset.

The Free tier supports max 500,000 objects in the directory so if you don't need the additional features, then the Free tier is probably fine.

More details here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/active-directory/

Comment: In that case, when we go for Premium one